# Gem::LoadError: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am doing `heroku run rake db:migrate`
and this is the error:

> Gem::LoadError: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter.
>   Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it
>   to your Gemfile.

**Gemfile:**

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
```

**Database.yml**

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: Unicode
```

Comment: `grep -r sqlite3 .` in your rails root.

Comment: Have you added `rails_12factor` gem?

Comment: what is your `RAILS_ENV`? Is that development or test?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved it downgrading the version that rails new installs by default.

remove the current version of the sqlite3 gem with 'gem uninstall sqlite3' then modify the GemFile to include the sqlite3 version. I my case I set the version '~1.3.6' and that soled the problem

Comment: I think version should be '~1.3.6'. use gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6' instead

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use use a different database other than sqlite,

1. remove sqlite3 in gemfile and bundle install
2. remove sqlite3 in database.yml
3. rake db:create <---------------- or will complain no db error in 
   browser

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 & below you need to 'rails_12factor'gem.... Rails 5 & above this is not required.

Also noticed you don't have sqlite3 in your development environment, it may not matter but just place it there for good measure.

Comment: "5 & below… 5 & above" is ambiguous. Is that gem required for Rails 5, or not? [I guess not](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor#rails-5).

Comment: it is not. Most likely the sqlite version simply needs to be fixed in the Gemfile: `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4.0'` (or some other version)

Comment: There's an error in your formulation: you implied both that Rails 5 needed and didn't need rails_12factor.